# How do I format a Number field in KeystoneJS?

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

Its the property 'referenceId' that I would like to format. Heres my model code:

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Stock = new keystone.List('Stock', {
    map: { name: 'adminDisplayTitle' },
    autocreate: true
});

Stock.add({
    adminDisplayTitle: { type: String, required: true , default: 'Title to show in this Admin UI'},
    referenceId: { type: Number, required: true },
    country: { 
        type: Types.Select, 
        options: [
            { value: 'sv', label: 'Sweden' },
            { value: 'fi', label: 'Finland' },
            { value: 'dk', label: 'Denmark' }
        ], 
        required: true
    },
    author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User' },
    rating: { type: String, required: true },
    rate: { type: Number, required: true },
    published: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

Stock.defaultColumns = 'adminDisplayTitle, referenceId, author, createdAt';

Stock.register();
```

Is there any way of declaring the formatting inside the model ? I cant seem to understand the documentation for this part.

Heres an image of the field with a comma inside if it, that I want to get rid of as this is a reference id, not a value of that kind.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Number fields](http://keystonejs.com/guide/data/#field_number) in [KeystoneJS](http://keystonejs.com) use the [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com) library for formatting values.

There's an option you can set on the field to control the default format string, which can be any valid format that numeral knows what to do with, e.g:

```
referenceId: { type: Number, format: '0', required: true }
```

The Admin UI will always format the value using the string in the `format` option. To remove all formatting (e.g. thousands delimiter) just set this to '0' as in the example above.

You can use the default format in your template by using the `.format` [underscore method](http://keystonejs.com/guide/data/#fields_underscoremethods) on the item:

```
div= stockItem._.format()
```

The underscore method accepts a string argument which overrides the `format` option set in the Model, so you can render it differently in your templates, e.g.

```
div= stockItem._.format('0,0');
```

The default format string for Number fields is `'0,0[.][000000000000]'`